# Как вывести содержимое таблицы paradox 5 в консоли?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.

Как вывести содержимое таблицы paradox 5 в консоли с#?

Comment: Вся проблема в том и заключается, что готовый ридер не скачать(сервер авторизации упал, видимо), а пример работы с базой попробую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тут](https://www.connectionstrings.com/paradox/) можно посмотреть `ConnectionString`. [Здесь](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Connecting-to-a-PARADOX-DB-with-C-(Vista-XP).aspx) пример работы с базой. А [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/101014/Paradox-database-native-NET-reader) вроде даже готовый ридер

С выводом данных в консоль, я думаю, проблем не будет

Answer (score 1):

Вам [сюда](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Connecting-to-a-PARADOX-DB-with-C-(Vista-XP).aspx), сам долго мучился как с этим разобраться, данная инструкция помогла. В ней описано как подключиться к BD paradox и сохранить результат запроса в DataGridView. Думаю как из DataGridView вытащить данные разберетесь.